# jest promise toThrow doesn't receive throw new Error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, jestjs

```
function getUserValue(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readLine("enter the number : ", (enter) => {
      if(enter.length > 3){
        throw new Error("some error")
      }
  )};
}
```

```
async function play(){
 try{
   await getUserValue();
 } catch(message){
   console.log(message);
 }
}
```

```
- jest -

test("exception test", expect(() => {
  const app = new App();
  app.play();
}).toThrow();
```

I want to receive the value through "getUserValue" using readLine of nodejs.
And I wanted to use async function to deal with errors. I tired to test this code using jest's toThrow. But it doesn't receive Error and doesn't work...
please help me.. What did I do wrong?

I really want to know how to handle error.

Comment: You are handling the error in the `play()` so it doesn't throw, and as a result the test fails. If you'd removed the try-catch block then it would pass, also since the `play()` method is asynchronous you should test it with `await expect(...).rejects.toMatchObject(Error("some error"))` or something like that.

Comment: I modified jest as you said, and it worked normally.
Thanks for your help!